# htaccess user profile folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my website there is a user profile file, which is in php. Where if you write http://www.youdomain.com/user.php?id=[user id]. It shows that users profile with the id.

Is there a way in htaccess that if a write http://www.youdomain.com/users/[user id] it will display the page http://www.youdomain.com?id=[user id].

Thank you.

Comment: You could get the href by `$(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.Nav a').each(function(e) {
    var href = e.attr("href");
    if (href === window.location.href) {
        alert(href);
    }
});
```